# 403 forbidden к папке .default Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Прошу помочь с проблемой. Только установил Битрикс и уже посыпались проблемы.
не подгружает какие то системные стили и картинки.
консоль ругается что не может получил

```
http://bitrix.dev/bitrix/themes/.default/compatible.css?14714950952827 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

В чем может быть дело?
сижу на винде, openserver php 5.5

Answer (score 3):

Для OpenServer в конфиге надо изменить строку

```
<LocationMatch "/\.(?!well-known)">
```

на

```
<LocationMatch "/\.(?!well-known|default)">
```

В зависимости от версии Apache
**\OpenServer\userdata\config**

Comment: Кто пользуется опенсервером, работает.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты могут быть разные:

- Не хватает прав на чтение из windows-папки
- Есть запреты в конфигурации apache
- Есть запреты в .htaccess

Comment: Просто у моего друга на денвере все прекрасно работает и доступ есть. Идентично установил как и я. Единственный вариант что в апаче опенсервера может что то не так?

Comment: В общем в настройках опенсервера былл апач 2.4 + nginx 1.7.
Поменял на просто "apache 2.4" Все прекрасно заработало...

Answer (score -1):

В настройках nginx нужно убрать эту строку:

> location ~ /. {deny all;}

Comment: очень плохой совет. [Скрытые директории и файлы как источник чувствительной информации о веб-приложении](https://hackware.ru/?p=7567)